# Searching all fields in Solr / SolrJ

Tags: java, solr, solrj

Is there an easy way to build a query that searches all fields in a Solr index using one call to Solr?

I can search for some text in all the fields by defining each field individually:

```
String textToSearchFor = "someText";
HttpSolrServer solrServer = new HttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8983/solr");

SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
query.setQuery( "customerName:" + textToSearchFor
                + " OR customerAddress:" + textToSearchFor
                + " OR customerNotes:" + textToSearchFor
                );
query.setQueryType("edismax");
QueryResponse rsp = solrServer.query( query );
```

The issue I have with this approach is that if a field is added or removed from the Solr schema, I have to update this code.  I would prefer that I set up my query request so that it searches all available fields without forcing me to specify each field name.

Can I accomplish this in a single call to the Solr server?  How?

Answer (score 2):

This is best accomplished in the schema itself. Define a `fullSearch` field (with the appropriate fieldType) and then use the copyField directive to copy all fields you want to search over into this new field. (Rebuild the index). Then in your query, you only search in this one field.

Answer (score 1):

I can see that you are already using the *Extended DisMax Query Parser*, which is designed for this purpose. You should read the documentation about the *[Dismax Query Parser](http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/The+DisMax+Query+Parser)*, which is some sort of father to the eDismax. The eDismax shares most of the features the dismax query parser offers.

You may configure default values within your solrconfig.xml for your requesthandler.

```
<requestHandler name="standard" class="solr.StandardRequestHandler" default="true">
<!-- default values for query parameters -->
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="defType">edismax</str>
    <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
    <!-- define the fields to query for here -->
    <str name="qf">customerName customerAddress customerNotes</str>
  </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

That way your java code will be reduced, as the queryType is already defined by default as edismax.

```
String textToSearchFor = "someText";
HttpSolrServer solrServer = new HttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8983/solr");

SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
query.setQuery(textToSearchFor);
QueryResponse rsp = solrServer.query( query );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Solr 3.6, then you can use User Fields. For details, see [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3026) JIRA issue and [this](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtendedDisMax#qf_.28Query_Fields.29) Wiki page.

You need to add the following either to the query or `solrconfig.xml`

> uf="* allFields"
>
> f.allFields.qf="customerName customerAddress customerNotes"

After that, just search in the field `allFields` and it will search in the 3 fields `customerName customerAddress customerNotes`. You can create as many such user fields as required.